# Symfony edit form dosen't work

Tags: php, forms, symfony, submit, edit

i want to edit my data with symfony form and i have a problem 
probably with my controller. I have some like this :

```
  public function detailAction($id,Request $request)
{
    $order = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(OrderMain::class)->find($id);

    if (!$order) {
        throw $this->notFoundException();
    }

    $form = $this->createForm(OrderMainType::class, $order);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
//            do not enter here
            $orderEdit = $form-getData();
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($orderEdit);
            $em->flush();
        }

    return $this->render('ModiModiAdminBundle:Order:detail.html.twig',array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
}


 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
   /.../
 ->add('edit', SubmitType::class, array(
                                  'attr' =>array('class'=>'edit'),
            ));
    }
```

All show corectly but when i click a button my page is reload ( dosen't save changes ). Thanks for help.

Comment: The entity manager doesn't know how to persist the form data, it only takes in entities. Try handing over the `$order` entity in your controller, which inside the isvalid condition block should be updated with the new and valid form data.

Comment: It's dosen't work :(

Answer (score 0):

It is an issue with your controller method. Below should work for you.

```
public function detailAction($id,Request $request)
{
    $order = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(OrderMain::class)->find($id);

    if (!$order) {
        throw $this->notFoundException();
    }

    $form = $this->createForm(OrderMainType::class, $order);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            //do not enter here
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->flush();
        }

    return $this->render('ModiModiAdminBundle:Order:detail.html.twig',array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
}
```

You can remove the line of `$orderEdit = $form-getData();`. When your form is submitted, the entity should be updated based on the submitted data. Since this is already a managed entity, you can also remove `$em->persist($orderEdit);`

Comment: Maybe it's work, but do not enter inside  if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())

Comment: What do you mean by "do not enter" after form is submitted and valid?

Comment: yes, $form->isSubmitted() and  $form->isValid() always return false

Comment: Then the issue is most likely in your form. If you are using the profile debugger, you should be able to see what data is being sent and any errors in the response.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function edit(Request $request)
{
 $id = $request->get('id');
 $category = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Category::class)->find($id);

    if (!$category) {
        throw $this->notFoundException();
    }
    $form = $this->createForm(CategoryType::class,$category);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $categoryData = $form->getData();
        $em->persist($categoryData);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->render('admin/category/edit.html.twig',array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

you are missing => handle request from code
$form->handleRequest($request);